# How to disconnect an rtmp connection?

Tags: red5, rtmp, openlaszlo, lzx

Do you know if it's possible actually to disconnect a rtmpconnection and how ?
There is no "disconnect" method in the official doc, and also in the rtmpconnection.lzx . So if you know a way out to disconnect the rtmp connection,please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [<rtmpconnection> class in OpenLaszlo](http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/lps/components/extensions/av/rtmpconnection.lzx) uses the [ActionScript 3 NetConnection clas](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)s to connect to the server. The NetConnection class has a [method close()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#close%28%29), here is the documentation for that:

> Closes the connection that was opened locally or to the server and
>   dispatches a netStatus event with a code property of
>   NetConnection.Connect.Closed.
>
> This method disconnects all NetStream objects running over the
>   connection. Any queued data that has not been sent is discarded. (To
>   terminate local or server streams without closing the connection, use
>   NetStream.close().) If you close the connection and then want to
>   create a new one, you must create a new NetConnection object and call
>   the connect() method again.
>
> The close() method also disconnects all remote shared objects running
>   over this connection. However, you don't need to recreate the shared
>   object to reconnect. Instead, you can just call SharedObject.connect()
>   to reestablish the connection to the shared object. Also, any data in
>   the shared object that was queued when you issued
>   NetConnection.close() is sent after you reestablish a connection to
>   the shared object.
>
> With Flash Media Server, the best development practice is to call
>   close() when the client no longer needs the connection to the server.
>   Calling close() is the fastest way to clean up unused connections. You
>   can configure the server to close idle connections automatically as a
>   back-up measure.

In the LZX source code for the <rtmpconnection> I can see that NetConnection.close() is only called in case of a connection failure:

```
<!--- Handle connection failure, attempt to reconnect using altsrc
      @keywords private -->
<method name="_handleConnectionFailure" args="msg"><![CDATA[
    this._nc.close();
    if (this.debug) {
        if ($debug) Debug.warn("error connecting to", this._connecturl, ":", msg);
    }
....
```

I don't know why there is no close method defined on the <rtmpconnection> class, but you could add that code for your yourself, by extending the <rtmpconnection> and adding a close method. Just make sure you handle the state variables correctly.

As I haven't used Red5 in a long time, I cannot tell you if Red5 automatically closes NetConnections which are idle.